# CSS Animations performance benchmark

Tags: javascript, css, performance, animation, benchmarking

I have a web-app with tons- literally- tons of special effects, mostly CSS transformations and opacity changes, that look sweet and professional, but for some users are a bit problematic though. I receive tickets that on some (mostly rather old) machines those animations are flickering and instead of giving pleasure to the eye they are annoying.

Here I am asking for a most efficient way of testing user performance, so I would be able to trigger some class on the `body` tag that will simplify some, or even turn off those animations for older machines.

My idea for now is to use some open source js benchmark (some test that uses canvas and takes no longer than 200ms) and cache results in localStorage. Problem is that when I open my app in a hidden tab, this benchmark show wrong results. How to tell user will have smooth 50-60fps experience without taking too much time to test and to have most reliable results?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> How to tell user will have smooth 50-60fps experience without taking too much time to test and to have most reliable results?

I don't think there is a way to do that. Potentially, you could order a service for that (like [CrossBrowserTesting](https://crossbrowsertesting.com/) or [Leaptest](https://leaptest.com/)) to get the video recording for those devices and see for yourself.

From personal experience - we removed all fancy CSS3 animations for Android tablets and iOS devices as those were crashing unexpectedly on our app.

Avoid having large layers with opacity animations, like modal windows backdrop, etc.

Generally - check the [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCtOt9OXvAM) and [articles](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/) on `repaint & reflow` in browsers and debug your app to see what is or might be causing issues for the users.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Here's also a good one - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/